# How to get body content from request in mobile service in Azure

Tags: azure

I crate a mobile service and also a custom api for that in Azure. I use fiddler to send request and do some basic and simple testing.

At Azure side, I create a custom api for my mobile service. Let say the name is ExampleCustomApi. And in the code I have

```
exports.put = function(request, response) {
     var tags = request.parameters.tags;
     ...
     ...
}
```

At fiddler side, I set http method to "PUT" and the url to my custom api.
Then I set a request body to { "tags": "tag1" }.

When I execute the request in fiddler, I receive 500 back. The log in Azure's mobile service says that parameters is undefined.

My question, then, is how to get the request body at the server side. I look at the document of request object, it seems to me that  parameters is the one I should use, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please expand your question and use correct tags. This isn't an Azure question. What is the API coded in, what is your code, what is it returning or what error is occurring? These are the things you need to list to get help.

Comment: @Adam Rephrase the question. This should be an Azure question. I'm using it's mobile service. In the code, request is provided by Azure. the question is how to get the body content in the http request from request object.

Answer (score 0):

request is an object in express.js library.
This is the documentation from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj554218.aspx
the documentation from express.js http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body
And I can use request.body to get the body content.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts we cracked getting the content from a weburl. Hope this helps :) Jsonbody would hold your page content. This is a copy where we pulled json from one of our API's

```
var message = "try";
var jsonBody = "";
var request = require('request');
request.get({
   url: "https://superduperwebaddress.com/api/pull"},
   function(error,response,body){
       if(!error)
       {
           var mybody = JSON.parse(body);
          jsonBody = mybody;
           console.warn("we are here well");

       }else{
          console.error(error);
       }
   } 
);
```